# How can I display data from multiple models in one view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have create an MVCApplication1 in that there are two model classes like this,

StudentPersonalInfo.cs

```
public class StudentPersonalInfo
{
      public string StudentFirstName { get; set; }
      public string StudentLastName { get; set; }
      public int Age { get; set; }
      public string BloodGroup { get; set; }
      public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

And 2nd one is

EducationQualification.cs

```
 public class EducationQualification
{
      public string Graduation { get; set; }
      public intGrad_Marks_obtain { get; set; }

      public DateTimeGrad_passing_year { get; set; }
      public stringPostGraduation { get; set; }

      public intPG_Marks_obtain { get; set; }
      public DateTimePG_passing_year { get; set; }
}
```

I wanted to show that both models data in one view page and I  don't know what to do next after creating this two models.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What do you want to do actually? Would you like to be more specific?

Comment: I m new in MVC. I dont know more about it. in that poject i want to create the two model classes and after that create another view model class and then call those objects in controller and i want only one controller of both model classes and only one view page for both classes.. and i dont know how to create and where to create a viewmodel and how to call the object in controller. so please help me :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class StudentPersonalInfo
{
      public string StudentFirstName { get; set; }
      public string StudentLastName { get; set; }
      public int Age { get; set; }
      public string BloodGroup { get; set; }
      public string Address { get; set; }
}

public class EducationQualification
{
      public string Graduation { get; set; }
      public int Grad_Marks_obtain { get; set; }

      public DateTime Grad_passing_year { get; set; }
      public string PostGraduation { get; set; }

      public int PG_Marks_obtain { get; set; }
      public DateTime PG_passing_year { get; set; }
}


public class StudentInfo
{
   public StudentPersonalInfo PersonalInfo {get;set;}
   public EducationQualification EducationalQualification {get;set;}
}
```

Now use **StudentInfo** Class as model in your view. Refer to both aggregated classes in view as:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.StudentPersonalinfo.StudentFirstname)
```

**Update**

**Students- Model**

```
public class StudentPersonalInfo
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string StudentFirstName { get; set; }
    public string StudentLastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string BloodGroup { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

public class EducationQualification
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Graduation { get; set; }
    public int Grad_Marks_obtain { get; set; }

    public DateTime Grad_passing_year { get; set; }
    public string PostGraduation { get; set; }

    public int PG_Marks_obtain { get; set; }
    public DateTime PG_passing_year { get; set; }
}



public class StudentInfo
{
    public StudentPersonalInfo PersonalInfo { get; set; }
    public EducationQualification EducationalQualification { get; set; }
}
```

**StudentsDbContext.cs**

```
public class StudentDbContext:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<StudentPersonalInfo> StudentPersonalInfos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EducationQualification> EducationQualifications { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(StudentInfo model)
    {
        var personalInfo = model.PersonalInfo;
        var educationQualification = model.EducationalQualification;
        using (var context = new StudentDbContext())
        {
            context.StudentPersonalInfos.Add(personalInfo);
            context.EducationQualifications.Add(educationQualification);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        return View();
    }
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div style="width:500px;margin:auto;">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Student Personal Info</legend>
            <p>Student First Name: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PersonalInfo.StudentFirstName)</p>
            <p>Student Last Name: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PersonalInfo.StudentLastName)</p>
            <p>Age: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PersonalInfo.Age)</p>
            <p>Blood Group: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PersonalInfo.BloodGroup)</p>
            <p>Address: @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.PersonalInfo.Address)</p>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Educational Qualification</legend>
            <p>Graduation: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EducationalQualification.Graduation)</p>
            <p>Grad. Marks Obtained: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EducationalQualification.Grad_Marks_obtain)</p>
            <p>Grad. Passing Year: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EducationalQualification.Grad_passing_year)</p>
            <p>PG: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EducationalQualification.PostGraduation)</p>
            <p>PG Marks Obtained: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EducationalQualification.PG_Marks_obtain)</p>
            <p>PG Passing Year: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EducationalQualification.PG_passing_year)</p>
        </fieldset>

        <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
    </div>
}
```

You're free to do validations and add styles as per your preference. This demo is just for reference purposes.

Here is a sample project based on your classes for demonstration purposes:

https://github.com/sunnykumar08/public

Hope it helps!

Comment: After creating both classes, and Student info am trying to create a controller but when i m going to create controller with read/write actions in EF template,

Comment: then it ask for model class and DbContext class but when pass the StudentInfo class and  StudentInfoDbContext

Comment: it Shows Error (Unable to retrive the metadatafor 'Demo.Models.StudentInfo'. one or more validation detecte during model generation: -System.data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType:: EntityType'StudentInfo' has no key defined.define the key for EntityType.-System.data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType:: Entityset'StudentInfo' is based on type StudentInfo has no key defined. )

Comment: You need to specify **id** to each of the entity/class.

Comment: please tell me how to add one controller and one view page for both classes.. how to do it please help

Comment: please refer to this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16801245/mvc-ef-code-first-creating-model-class

Comment: can u tell me how to  add one controller and one view page for both classes

Comment: don't forget to mark the reply as answer if it solved your purpose... thanks!

Comment: sir, when i run this code as you suggest, it create the one view page successful and display all those fields in one view page, but when i enter data in it and try to save it, it display this error,(One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'InstituteInformation' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet 'InstInfoDbset' is based on type 'InstituteInformation' that has no keys defined.)

Comment: i have specify id to each of the entity/class

Comment: download and go through the sample project at github, refer to updated answer for the link. Cheers!!

Comment: sir, i had download that project but when i tried to open it but its not open. please tell me how to dipaly the list from different models.. see updated question above

Comment: @Anonymous try opening the solution file in Visual Studio 2012!

Comment: Sir I write the following code for Display the Data in List // GET: /StudInfo/ public ActionResult Index1(StudentInfo model, StudentDbContext context) { var PI = model.PersonalInfo; var EQ = model.EducationalQualification; context.StudentPersonalInfos.ToList(); context.EducationQualifications.ToList(); return View(context); }

Comment: when I add the view like this

    <h2>Index1</h2>

    <p>
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create") %>
    </p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
    <%:Html. DisplayNameFor (m=>m.PersonalInfo.StudentFirstName) %>
    </th>
        </tr>

    <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
        <tr>
    <td>
    <%:Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.PersonalInfo.StudentFirstName) %>
    </td>
            <td>
                <%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) %> |
            </td>
        </tr>
    <% } %>

    </table>

Comment: here i try to write the following

<th>
<%:Html. DisplayNameFor (m=>m.PersonalInfo.StudentFirstName) %>
</th>
And
td>
<%:Html.DisplayFor(m=>m.PersonalInfo.StudentFirstName) %>
</td>Then it display this error

'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'PersonalInfo' and no extension method 'PersonalInfo' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Sir please tell me, is this code correct or not,,,,,,,,, Or how to dipaly the list from different models

Comment: Sir,i opened that project and run. now its running successfully.... Please see the above question which i posted...

Comment: @Anonymous: dear friend, you need to learn the basics first! Go start it here: http://www.asp.net/mvc

Answer (score 0):

You create objects based on your models:

```
StudentPersonalInfo myStudent = new StudentPersonalInfo();
EducationQualification myQualification = new EducationQualification();
```

You can be more specific? You can do several things, you can manipulate them in many other ways.